# How to find solution of this eigenfuction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

The eigen function boundary value problem is ($y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and similar for $y''$)
$$
y'' - \lambda y = 0,\\ y'(0) = y(2)=0
$$
I think the solution is like this

Case 1: $\lambda <0 $ putting $ \lambda = -m^2 \implies y = C_1 cos(mx) + C_2 sin(mx)$

Case 2: $\lambda >0 $ putting $ \lambda = m^2 \implies y = C_3 e^{mx} + C_4 e^{-mx}$

Case 3: $\lambda =0  \implies y = C_5 x + C_6 $

Case 1 gives 
$$
C_2=0\\ C_1 cos(2m)=0 \implies m=\frac{(2n+1) \pi}{4},n=0,1,2,3....
$$
so, case 1 eigenfunction is 
$$
y_n=C_n cos \bigg ( \frac{(2n+1) \pi}{4} x\bigg ) 
$$

Case 2 gives 
$$
y = C_3 e^{mx} + C_4 e^{-mx}\\
y' = C_3 m e^{mx} + C_4 m  e^{-mx} \\
y'(0)=0 \implies C_3 m - C_4 m  = 0 \implies C_3  - C_4   = 0, m=0 \\
y(1)=0 \implies C_3 e^{2m} + C_4 =0
$$

Here I am stuck at last two conditions. What is eigenvalue and eigenfuction from the last two conditions?

Case 3 gives 
$$
C_5 = C_6 =0
$$
So, are there no eigenvalues and eignefunctions?

Any help or suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps.

\begin{eqnarray*}
-\partial _{x}^{2}y(x) &=&-\lambda y(x) \\
\int_{0}^{2}dx\{-\partial _{x}^{2}y(x)\}y(x) &=&\left[ \{-\partial
_{x}^{{}}y(x)\}y(x)\right] _{0}^{2}+\int_{0}^{2}dx\{\partial _{x}y(x)\}^{2}
\\
&=&\int_{0}^{2}dx\{\partial _{x}y(x)\}^{2}=-\lambda \int_{0}^{2}dxy(x)^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Since the left hand side is non-negative and if $y(x)$ not identically $0$, $\lambda $ cannot be positive. If
it is $0$ and $y(x)$ not identically zero then $\partial _{x}y(x)$ must
vanish for all $x$ leaving constant $y(x)$ and hence, given $y(2)=0$, vanishing $y(x)$.